# Save data variables from matlab to a csv or text file

Tags: matlab

I have a for loop that loop for k iterations and each time I save the output from the iteration into a variable see code below:

```
dist(k)=sum(input~=Chosen_Output);
fprintf('dist%d = %f \n', k, dist(k))
```

I want to save all of the 'dist(k)' into a csv file I tried 'dlmwrite('test.csv',dist(k))' and 'save test.csv dist(k)' but they only save the 'dist' is there a way that I can save all of the 'dist(k)'?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fprintf` can be used to write to a file as well. [Please see the `fprintf` documentation here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).

Following example shows how to write a mat to a CSV file.

```
data = [1, 2, 3;
    4, 5, 6;
    7, 8, 9];

fid = fopen('dataCSV.csv', 'w');

for r = 1: size(data,1)
    fprintf(fid, '%d %d %d\n', data(r,1), data(r,2), data(r,3));
end
```

Comment: I tried it but still the output has the last 'dist' only not all of them i.e. my 'k' is 50, so, the output file doesn't have except 'dist50' and I need them all from 'dits1 --> dist50'. Thanks

Comment: Since your dist is not clear to me, I added a code segment in the answer on how to write a mat to a CSV file.